# git skip-worktree on files with merge conflict

Tags: git, git-skip-worktree

I have a configuration file `abc.cfg` with local changes for my environment. To prevent pushing local configs to the remote, I use `git update-index --skip-worktree abc.cfg` on the file.

Now the upstream has changed `abc.cfg` with global updates that I need. So I first did `--no-skip-worktree abc.cfg`, did `git stash` on it, pulled the upstream, and proceed with `git stash apply` on the file.

Now there's merge conflicts on `abc.cfg`. I tried to resolve it, and do `git update-index --skip-worktree abc.cfg` again, but this time it says:

```
fatal: Unable to mark file scripts/app.js
```

How should I apply back my local changes without including it in the commits?

Answer (score 0):

I think your project is a mobile application project as you have error in scripts/app.js

You are applying stash, still ignoring it and not want to push your local changes, thats fine. There should not be any issue due to this.

Now, the error you got `fatal: Unable to mark file scripts/app.js`, I guess its due to the changes you pulled from remote. Do this, take a fresh copy of remote at different location and use any compare tool to see what all files are different in two projects specially the app.js file.

Comment: Hi Jyoti, it's well known to me that remote has changed app.js, what happens is that when I apply the stash, the file contains merge conflict. And after I solved the conflict, I still can't just skip-worktree on the file.

Answer (score 0):

> Now there's merge conflicts on `abc.cfg`.
> I tried to resolve it, and do `git update-index --skip-worktree abc.cfg` again, but...

The is a corner case which could prevent `git skip-worktree` to work as intended in case of merge conflict.

When the sparse checkout feature is in use, "`git cherry-pick`" and other mergy operations **lost the `skip_worktree` bit** when a path that is excluded from checkout requires content level merge, which is resolved as the same as the HEAD version, without materializing the merge result in the working tree, which made the path appear as deleted.

This has been corrected in Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) by preserving the `skip_worktree` bit (and not materializing the file in the working tree).

See [commit 2b75fb6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b75fb601c05a789988cf0e1b3c1375ee62d3c3e) (27 Jul 2018) by [Elijah Newren (`newren`)](https://github.com/newren).
See [commit 92203e6](https://github.com/git/git/commit/92203e6432cd77c3dfc82bd475a4c802085cffcb) (27 Jul 2018) by [Ben Peart (`benpeart`)](https://github.com/benpeart).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e4095da](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e4095da40eef81f853bbeedf44d7f344bf682232), 15 Aug 2018)</sup>

> ### merge-recursive: preserve skip_worktree bit when necessary
>
> merge-recursive takes any files marked as unmerged by unpack_trees, tries to figure out whether they can be resolved (e.g. using renames or a file-level merge), and then if they can be it will delete the old cache entries and writes new ones.
>
> This means that any `ce_flags` for those cache entries are essentially cleared when merging.
>
> Unfortunately, if a file was marked as `skip_worktree` and it needs a file-level merge but the merge results in the same version of the file that was found in `HEAD`, we skip updating the worktree (because the file was unchanged) but clear the `skip_worktree` bit (because of the `delete-cache-entry-and-write-new-one`).
>
> This makes git treat the file as having a local change in the working copy, namely a delete, when it should appear as unchanged despite not being present.
> Avoid this problem by copying the `skip_worktree` flag in this case.